# Nodejs upload images to other server API

Tags: php, node.js, request, image-uploading, multer

I was wondering if any one can help with following issue.

I have an Api with node/express for image uploads

#### server1

```
var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/'})
app.post('/api/upload', upload.single('file'), function(req, res, next) {

if (req.file && req.file.path) { 
   //used to have imgur upload
   //imgur.uploadFile(req.file.path)
   //           .then(function (json) {
   //});
}
});
```

#### server2

I have PHP Api for image uploads as well which I have set up for self-hosting using pictshare. I want to redirect file uploads to new API by redirecting uploads to PHP Api server.

Have tried `multer`, `multiparty`, `needle`, `request` and various other methods... but somehow couldn't figure out.

Is there way to direct multer to new destination?

File is being saved in `uploads/` folder, maybe better would be to upload/direct that file to new server and return new url from server2 ?

Looked around for pipelining upload images, with not much luck..

note: server1 api is being used by mobile app so wouldn't want to release app update if it can be handled from server side.

Answer (score 0):

To upload a file (image or whatever) you need to have it in your drive first (or in memory, but I will tackle the drive case first). Then you can read it and send it.

The APIs that receive files use to receive forms. Usually they expect to receive a form where the attachment comes as a `file` field.

Here you can see a working example uploading an existing file in my drive to an external API by using the ['superagent'](https://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/) library for Node.

```
const
  fs = require('fs'),
  agent = require('superagent');
  const stream = fs.createReadStream('path/to/downloaded/file');
 agent.post(`urlOfApi/uploadFileEndpoint`)
  .type('form')
  .attach('file', stream.path);
```